# How do i connect Directus on the Digital Ocean App Platform to an external MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean, directus

I have a Directus instance deployed on the Digital Ocean App Platform through a Docker container.
I need to connect it to an external SQL database. I have set all the necessary environment variables for connecting to the database, but it doesn't seem to be connecting to it though it is live.
How do I ensure it is connected to the external database?